# JS array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a paragraph stored in a variable named `story`.

`story = story text;`
(example).

The first step in the project is to separate each word in the story variable and store it in an array named `storyWords`.

Easy enough, check.

Now it wants us to iterate through `storyWords`, filter out `unnecessaryWords` and store the new array in a variable named `betterWords`.

`unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually'];`

Here is my code:

```
const betterWords = storyWords.filter(word => {
  if(word !== unnecessaryWords)
    return word;
});
```

What leads me to believe that this should work is based on this code:

```
const betterWords = storyWords.filter(word => {
  if(word !== 'extremely')
   if(word !== 'literally')
    if(word !== 'actually')
     return word;
})
```

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: `unnecessaryWords = 'extremely', 'literally', 'actually';` Is that your actual code? If so, you're invoking the comma operator, and only the `actually` is being assigned, the others are being lost

Comment: sorry, it is not. unnecessaryWords is an array.

Comment: _"Easy enough, check."_  I'd love to see this part because the definition of a _"word"_ is highly variable

Comment: FYI, the callback to `Array.prototype.filter()` should return a `Boolean`. You are returning a string or `undefined`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try two approaches. Using a `Array.forEach()` and `Array.filter()` like i demonstrated below.

```js
// Just for Illustration, let's initialize a list representing storyWords
var storyWords = ['story','extremely', 'global','actually', 'javascript','c-sharp','literally'];

var unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually'];

//First using simple loop
var betterWordsLooped = [];

storyWords.forEach((word)=>
{
  if(!unnecessaryWords.includes(word))
  {
    betterWordsLooped.push(word);
  }
});

console.log(betterWordsLooped);

//Secondly Using Filter
var betterWordsFiltered = storyWords.filter((word)=> !unnecessaryWords.includes(word));

console.log(betterWordsFiltered);
```

On this code:
`!unnecessaryWords.includes(word))`
we want to check if the value of variable `word` matches any of the items contained in the string array `unnecessaryWords`. Remember the pattern for using `Array.propotype.includes()` is `someArray.includes(someVar)` where `someArray` is a `[]` and `someVar` is a string variable whose value you want to match within `someArray`.

Comment: I was under the assumption that they wanted us to return an array from the function. Initializing a new array and using .push works fine. What I don't understand is why it has to be written like this:

!unnecessaryWords.includes(word) 

instead of:

word.includes(!unnecessaryWords)

Comment: `word.includes(!unnecessaryWords)` here  `word` is a string and not a list. `unnecessaryWords` is a list. you can only check if `word` is included inside `unnecessaryWords`

Comment: I'm going to just  change the code a little bit with comments so that you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude the entry as long as it matches *any* of the unnecessary words that is an array:

```
const unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually'];
```

...then you can simply return `!unnecessaryWords.includes(word)`, which means "if `word` is not included in the array of `unnecessaryWords`, we want to keep it":

```
const betterWords = storyWords.filter(word => !unnecessaryWords.includes(word));
```

[`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) will return true when `word` matches any of the array members in `unnecessaryWords`.

Proof-of-concept:

```js
const unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually'];
const storyWords = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'extremely', 'dolor', 'sit', 'actually', 'amet'];

const betterWords = storyWords.filter(word => !unnecessaryWords.includes(word));

console.log(betterWords);
```

Comment: No, it wants us to store the remaining words in the variable betterWords.

Comment: @nmA Just updated my answer: shouldn't it do what you expected? If your `storyWords` contain the members `['foo', 'bar', 'extremely']` then it `betterWords` will be `['foo', 'bar']`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: I have fixed the post but the original post may have been misleading.

let story = 'This is an example of the really cool string';
const storyWords = story.split(' ');
let unnecessaryWords = ['really', 'cool'];

Now we want to filter out the unnecessary words and store the result in betterWords.

Comment: @nmA And the code should work as expected the way you described.

Comment: yes it does, thank you. I was overlooking the syntax for .includes().

Answer (score 0):

The following uses a regular expression and [String#matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to match word character sequences following a word boundary. [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is then used to filter out the unnecessary words.

```js
const unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually']

function betterWords(text) {
  const words = [...text.matchAll(/\b\w+/gu)].flat()
  return words.filter((w) => !unnecessaryWords.includes(w))
}

const text = 'literally the story text'
console.log(betterWords(text))
```